# How to fix all/most dependency errors for android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, duplicates, dependencies

I keep getting a "duplicate class" for my dependencies but I cannot figure out which one it is. I need all of them.

I've tried removing one at a time to see if the error goes away, however it just gives a different error, basically telling me that I need that dependency.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
}
```

A couple of lines of the error. Didn't give the full error because TLDR.

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzfq found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.4)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzfr found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.4)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzfs found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.4)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzft found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.4)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzfu found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.4)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzfv found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.4)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzfw found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.4)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzfx found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.4)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzfy found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.4)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzfz found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.0.0) and classes.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.4)
```

Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, those classes are in both the modules. I got this error when trying to use aws services on my app. You can exclude the module which is duplicated something like this:

`implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'){
        exclude group:'com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement'
 }`